# Car the edge flow

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow

[image]
[image]

i feel like something is really wrong with this side , I used the edge flow addon but it still only gave me this I couldn't figure out how to proceed from here without making the mesh look all clucky

Comment: I don't think you need so many edge loops on the bevel face. Also, do you have a reason to do it with only one mesh? It doesn't simplify your work...

Comment: i used the edge loops to  get get window's edges shaped like that it might not have been optimal but using only 1 mesh and edgelooping it into more more complex shapes has been the only workflow i have really tried. i don't really know how to use more meshes without ruining collisions later on or whatever .

Comment: you have methods to reduce the topology, as explained here: https://topologyguides.com/   about one mesh, I don't think you'll ruin your collision, I guess it would even make more sense to have several meshes

Comment: wouldn't the vertices of the added mesh that wouldn't be visible slow the render time or make the model unoptimized in a way ? thank you very much btw

Comment: if the vertices are not visible you can delete them actually

Comment: thank you, i'll research topology more before going in any further into complex models .